# Proper directory structure for composer packages that require other composer packages?

Tags: php, composer-php

Say for example if I want to create an MVC composer plugin that require Doctrine ORM, I would add doctrine to that plugin's composer.json's "require", right?

Now what if I wish to create a project that require that MVC composer plugin that I just created. Do I need to add doctrine to this project's composer.json's "require"?

In Symfony it does seem I would need to include Doctrine ORM again, but is there anyway possible to make this inclusion recursive somehow?

Thank you!

**Edit**

It was probably caused by my mistake in directory setup. Let me know if that is the case, here is my setup:

```
App
 -- my app classes (Controllers, Models, etc.)
library
 -- my
   -- library
     -- Class
     composer.json (in here I have require doctrine)
vendor
composer.json (I do not require doctrine here, 
should doctrine be added to my project when I do composer update in this case?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer will resolve dependencies of dependencies, that's exactly the point. You can simply `require` a component, and that component can `require` other components etc. ad infinitum, and Composer will sort it all out and install all required dependencies.

Comment: It is probably my directory arrangements that was wrong. I have added more information in my question, please let me know if that was indeed the case?

Comment: Are you saying you have two `composer.json` files at different levels? You should have 1) your library packaged as a Composer package with its normal `composer.json` file in a separate repository, 2) your app with its `composer.json` file in which you `require` your library. Then run Composer and it will install your library into the vendor folder, together with the dependencies of said library.

Comment: Alright, I understand now, like what you wrote. Apparently I misunderstood "require" and "autoload" items in composer.json - Composer may only require a plugin's requirements when that plugin is added into "require".